# How to reuse test file in detox

Tags: react-native, testing, mobile, automated-tests, detox

I have an app where I am signing in and doing stuff. I want to reuse my signIn.e2e.js file. Basically I want to test dashboard, so I want to log in before that. Hence I want to use my signIn.e2e.js file in homeScreen.e2e.js file.

Any idea how I can do that?

I tried to do some research but haven't found anything. I am using jest test runner, it does have jest-runner-groups, but that's for jest, not for Detox.